# Executing an EXE file using a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to execute an EXE file using a PowerShell script. If I use the command line it works without a problem (first I supply the name of the executable and series of parameters to invoke it):

```
"C:\Program Files\Automated QA\TestExecute 8\Bin\TestExecute.exe" C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs /run /exit /SilentMode
```

But doing the exact same thing inside of a script returns an error:

> **The term** '"C:\Program Files\Automated
>   QA\TestExecute 8\Bin\TestExecute.exe"
>   C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs
>   /run /exit /SilentMode' **is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.**

(I invoked the command using the "&" operator.)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Post your code, please. Since that's where the problem lies, having it to look at is much easier than guessing.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
& "C:\Program Files\Automated QA\TestExecute 8\Bin\TestExecute.exe" C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs /run /exit /SilentMode
```

or

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("C:\Program Files\Automated QA\TestExecute 8\Bin\TestExecute.exe", "C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs /run /exit /SilentMode")
```

UPDATE: sorry I missed "(I invoked the command using the "&" operator)" sentence. I had this problem when I was evaluating the path dynamically. Try Invoke-Expression construction:

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\Program Files\Automated QA\TestExecute 8\Bin\TestExecute.exe`" C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs /run /exit /SilentMode"
```

Comment: Odd that the command in the original question, nearly exactly, works for me on a VM in PS2.0.  But that same command now fails on PS4.0 system.  Interestingly enough, I'm calling TestExecute also.  I think I like option 2 best, I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 60):

It looks like you're specifying both the EXE and its first argument in a single string e.g; `'"C:\Program Files\Automated QA\TestExecute 8\Bin\TestExecute.exe" C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs /run /exit /SilentMode'`.  This won't work. In general you invoke a native command that has a space in its path like so:

```
& "c:\some path with spaces\foo.exe" <arguments go here>
```

That is `&` expects to be followed by a string that identifies a command: cmdlet, function, native exe relative or absolute path.

Once you get just this working:

```
& "c:\some path with spaces\foo.exe"
```

Start working on quoting of the arguments as necessary.  Although it looks like your arguments should be just fine (no spaces, no other special characters interpreted by PowerShell).

Comment: Is there anyway to execute the powershell script without the full path, if the script and exe are in the same folder? Or is it possible to use a relative path?

Comment: If the exe is in the same folder then you can do this `.\foo.exe` and you can also use a relative path `..\..\foo.exe` and a relative path with spaces `& '..\..\path with spaces\foo.exe'`.

Comment: When you have **pipes** in your command than you should use quotes: `cmd /c "C:\temp\strarc.exe -cjd:M:\ | C:\temp\strarc.exe -s:8 -xd:N:\"`.

Answer (score 5):

In the Powershell, cd to the .exe file location. For example:

cd C:\Users\Administrators\Downloads

PS C:\Users\Administrators\Downloads> **& '.\aaa.exe'**

The installer pops up and follow the instruction on the screen.

Comment: exactly what I want! run an .exe file & '.\aaa.exe'

Answer (score 4):

1. clone $args
2. push your args in new array
3. & $path $args

Demo:

```
$exePath = $env:NGINX_HOME + '/nginx.exe'
$myArgs = $args.Clone()

$myArgs += '-p'
$myArgs += $env:NGINX_HOME

& $exepath $myArgs
```

Comment: Thx @nodoccat, worked like a charm to launch a docker command with a very long list of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variation on some of the previous responses. Either of the below options can be added to a Powershell profile to suit your needs.

##### Use an alias

If you just want to run something without mucking up `$env:PATH`.

```
Set-Alias -Name docker -Value 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe'
```

##### Use a function

Or if you need more scripting.

```
function docker {
# below is a basic example - go crazy here
& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe' @Args
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not being a developer I found a solution in running multiple ps commands in one line. E.g:

```
powershell "& 'c:\path with spaces\to\executable.exe' -arguments ; second command ; etc
```

By placing a " (double quote) before the & (ampersand) it executes the executable. In none of the examples I have found this was mentioned. Without the double quotes the ps prompt opens and waits for input.

Comment: Hi RichardE. Can you improve the formatting of your answer ? In edit mode, formatting help is provided, take a look at it.