# How to run C# console app using powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, console-application

I have a C# console application that reads .csv files. I want to run this in the middle of a powershell script. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the responses everyone. I'm new to this stuff so sorry for the duplicate question. I tried looking but couldn't find an answer to my question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Start-Process`, perhaps with the `-PassThru` option, for example:

```
$csvProc = Start-Process my_csv_reader.exe -PassThru
```

This would allow you to do something like `$csvProc | Stop-Process` later on, or to check if it's still running at a later point in your script through `$csvProc.HasExited`

If you need even more control, you could do it this way:

```
$csvProc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
```

and then you can use `$csvProc` the same way you'd use ProcessStartInfo in C# (setting the file name, paramaters, redirecting standard in or out, starting the process, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

If your executable isn't in your path you will need to tell powershell where to find it.

```
& "c:\some path with spaces\foo.exe" <arguments go here>
```

This has been answered before, here:
[Executing an EXE file using a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639894/executing-an-exe-file-using-powershell-script)

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
Start-Process -Wait PathToFile
```

If you don't want to wait for the process to finish remove the "-Wait" switch.