# Alternate for esbimportutil.exe for PowerShell BizTalk

Tags: powershell, deployment, biztalk, esb, biztalk-2013

I am working on a PowerShell Deployment scripts for BizTalk. I want to import an itinerary in XML format using PowerShell. Commands available for this task is **esbimportutil.exe**. But this works only in Command Prompt and not in PowerShell.

The error shows is :

> The term 'esbimportutil.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
>   or operable program.

I run the PowerShell as an Administrator and even tried running the command from the source root location but still no use.

Comment: Where is esbimportutil.exe located? Good chance that it is not in your PATH and you need to either add the folder to path or reference the full path to the exe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing an EXE file using a PowerShell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639894/executing-an-exe-file-using-a-powershell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. The problem was resolved by using a simple command:

Start-Process -FilePath "...\esbimportutil.exe" -ArgumentList $argument

The command "**start-process**" did the magic.