# In powershell, how do I specify path to an exe including $env:userprofile?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script to run an `exe` that would be located inside `userprofile` folder, but I cant seem to get the command working. Any idea how I can get this working?

I tried:
`$env:userprofile\es-cli\es.exe myParameter`

I got an error saying:
`Unexpected token '\es-cli\es.exe' in expression or statement.`

Also tried:

`($env:userprofile)\es-cli\es.exe myParameter` got an error `unexpected token \es-cli\es.exe`

`` `$($env:userprofile)\es-cli\es.exe myParameter` `` got an error `the term $ is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...`

`$loc = "{0}\es-cli\es.exe" -f $env:userprofile
 $loc myParameter # cant do this because $loc is a string`

Comment: Does it print out to the correct path if you wrap it in quotes?

Comment: @OwainEsau, based on your comment I tried `&"$env:userprofile\es-cli\es.exe"  and that worked! thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639894/executing-an-exe-file-using-a-powershell-script) SO post. I ended up doing below:

`& ("{0}\es-cli\es.exe" -f $env:userprofile) myParameter`

Based on the comment from Mathias below, I ended up using:

`&(Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'es-cli\es.exe') myParam`

Comment: This will work, but you might want to get in to the habit of using `Join-Path`: `& (Join-Path $env:userprofile 'es-cli\es.exe') myParameter`

Comment: Thank-you @MathiasR.Jessen! I like your way better, would definitely use that, thanks!

Comment: Since you don't state what `$env:userprofile` actually evaluates to, presumably that path has spaces in it?

Comment: in my case, `$env:userprofile` evaluates to `c:\users\anish`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a lot more code. But I like it as it give you more control over how your launched program behaves, stats, getting return codes, and errors back when needed. This is the long way to do the Startprocess method.

```
$Path = "$($env:userprofile)\es-cli\es.exe"
$Args = "myParameter"
$newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $Path;
$newProcess.Arguments = $Args
$RunPro2 = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$RunPro2.StartInfo = $NewProcess
$RunPro2.Start()
$RunPro2.WaitForExit()
$ProcessExitCode = $RunPro2.ExitCode.ToString()
```

Comment: Though `ProcessStartInfo` offers a lot more customization, this particular scenario could also be written as `$ProcessExitCode = (Start-Process -FilePath $Path -ArgumentList $Args -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode`.  The key point for this question, of course, is the string interpolation with `"$($env:userprofile)\es-cli\es.exe"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the call operator should work:

```
& $env:userprofile\es-cli\es.exe myParameter
```

Assuming you don't want to just add it to the path:

```
$env:path += ";$env:userprofile\es-cli"
es myParameter
```