# databricks-cli installed, modules not visible

Tags: powershell, databricks, databricks-cli

I installed the Databricks CLI, but I am unable to work with the library as such:

In powershell, I have set the working directory to: C:\Users\DNaught1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts

I know the module is there:

> Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
>
> -a----        13/10/2020   1:46 PM          74752 databricks.exe**

I then try to see the version but no luck as shown below:

```
PS C:\Users\DNaught1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts> databricks --version
```

> databricks : The term 'databricks' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - databricks --version
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (databricks:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```
>
> Suggestion [3,General]: The command databricks was not found, but does
> exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load
> commands from the current location by default. If you trust this
> command, instead type: ".\databricks". See "get-help
> about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing an EXE file using a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639894/executing-an-exe-file-using-a-powershell-script)

Comment: Use `.\databricks.exe --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around it by using the following:

1- In Python use the command below to install the CLI module

```
package_names=['databricks-cli', 'requests'] #packages to install
pip.main(['install'] + package_names + ['--upgrade'])
```

2- In powershell cli:
change the context to the working directory:

```
Set-Location -Path C:\Users\DNaught1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

3 - Configure the databricks cli:

```
.\databricks.exe configure--token
.\databricks configure --token
Host: https://xxx.azuredatabricks.net
Token: dapi2b2dxxxxxxxxxa02c9e6866d322 - Access token for Secrets
```

4 - Write-host Configuration file for databricks access

```
Set-Content .databrickscfg "[DEFAULT]"
>> Add-Content .databrickscfg "host = https://xxx.azuredatabricks.net"
>> Add-Content .databrickscfg "token = dapi2b2dxxxxxxxxxa02c9e6866d322"
```

5 - Validate by checking file storage

```
.\dbfs ls
```

Comment: I still get the error as its not recognized. Can you please help? ```PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> pip install databricks-cli
Requirement already satisfied: databricks-cli in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (0.16.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.17.3 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from databricks-cli) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.1.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from databricks-cli) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=6.7 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from databricks-cli) (8.1.3)
```

Comment: ```Requirement already satisfied: tabulate>=0.7.7 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from databricks-cli) (0.8.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjwt>=1.7.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from databricks-cli) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from databricks-cli) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from click>=6.7->databricks-cli) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->databricks-cli) (1.26.7)
```

Comment: ```Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->databricks-cli) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->databricks-cli) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->databricks-cli) (2.0.10)
```

Comment: ```PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> databricks -v
databricks: The term 'databricks' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.```