# Can't import publications using academic import --bibtex

Tags: function, powershell, visual-studio-code, helper, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to import publications using the call

`academic import --bibtex <path_to_your/publications.bib>`

but I get the error message `academic : The term 'academic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if  a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Any help is appreciated.

I call `cd` and the directory is C:\Users\CHRIS\OneDrive\Website_2021\academic-kickstart> which is where the .bib file is located.....

Comment: Try `& academic.exe import ...`

Comment: @Tomalak still the same :-( 

i tried ```& academic.exe import --bibtex c:\Users\CHRIS\OneDrive\Website_2021\academic-kickstart\pubs.bib```

Comment: Try to specify full path to `academic.exe`. Otherwise, the directory path must be contained in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @zett42 thank you, how do I do/try this?

Comment: `& "C:\Full\Path\To\academic.exe" import --bibtex c:\Users\CHRIS\OneDrive\Website_2021\academic-kickstart\pubs.bib`

Comment: @zett42 thank you for this...... I search the laptop but I don't have any academic.exe ?? Is this something I install within PowerShell or VSC?

Comment: So there we have the problem. I don't know what `academic.exe` is and where you get it from. I guess you have to download and install it from somewhere.

Comment: @zett42 managed to do it!! Many thanks for your help. Really appreciate it

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate: [Executing an EXE file using a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639894/executing-an-exe-file-using-a-powershell-script)