# how to run .exe file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, syntax-error, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

how do i run a .exe file by writing a line in powershell if my .exe file is located in "C:\Program Files\Rainmeter" and the name of the file is Rainmeter.exe ?

im just trying to make a script sry if this question is dumb

i have already tried these lines

 C:
13:18:42 ❯ cd C:\Program Files\Rainmeter>.\Rainmeter.exe
Set-Location: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\Rainmeter>.\Rainmeter.exe'.

 C:
13:18:58 ❯ cd C:\Program Files\Rainmeter.\Rainmeter.exe
Set-Location: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\Rainmeter.\Rainmeter.exe'.

 C:
13:19:14 ❯ cd C:\Program Files\Rainmeter.\Rainmeter.exe
Set-Location: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\Rainmeter.\Rainmeter.exe'.

 C:
13:04:43 ❯ c:\Program Files\Rainmeter>.\Rainmeter.exe
c:\Program: The term 'c:\Program' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

 C:
13:07:09 ❯ cd C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe
Set-Location: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe'.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your question can be found in this thread:
[Executing an EXE file using a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639894/executing-an-exe-file-using-a-powershell-script)

Example code:

```
& "c:\temp\foo.exe"
```